# like #if in c, is there `if in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How to compare the Macro with constants in Verilog?. Below code is giving error.

```
module top;
  `define A 10

  `if (`A==10)
    initial $display("10");
  `else
    initial $display("11");
  `endif

endmodule
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no `if in verilog, so you can't do it quite as you suggest.

You do have ifdef and ifndef, though, but it doesn't give you the opportunity to compare values. One cumbersome workaround is to have a set of preprocessed comparison-results, for instance like:

```
`ifdef A_EQUALS_10
    initial $display("10");
`else
    initial $display("11");
`endif
```

In the specific case you ask for, you should replace the `if with a plain if, i.e. not preprocessor version. And you need to put it inside a separate initial block, something like this:

```
initial
  begin
    if (`A==10)
      $display("10");
    else
      $display("11");
  end
```

In many cases, you should consider if define-statements should rather be replaced by parameter or localparam statements, which is a cleaner way to parameterize your design.

You may also read about this topic here:

http://www.veripool.org/papers/Preproc_Good_Evil_SNUGBos10_paper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generate construct's conditional `if` statement. First introduced in Verilog IEEE1364-2001 (see § 12.1.3 *Generated instantiation*). You can also read about it in SystemVerilog [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) (free to download from IEEE) in § 27 *Generate constructs*

```
module top;
  `define A 10

  generate
  if (`A==10) begin
    initial $display("10");
  end
  else begin
    initial $display("11");
  end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

The generate construct is intended to conditionally instantiate instances of modules. You can put procedural blocks (`initial`, `always`, `final`, etc) within a generate construct, but most of the time it is preferred to put the condition(s) within the procedural blocks.

```
initial begin
  if (`A==10)
    $display("10");
  else
    $display("11");
end
```

Be aware that compiler directives (e.g. `` `define ``, `` `ifdef ``, and other `` ` ``) are compiled and evaluated first by the order the files were compiled and ignore generate constructs. Therefore you cannot conditionally declare an `` `define `` inside of a generate constructs.